# How to animate @State value that is passed through a custom struct in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently making the authentication view for my app, and I want to add some movement. I decided that using animation to change the custom corner radius of my view would do the trick.

I've attached a link below of what it looks like currently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ4OO.png

Here is the code that specifically handles the corner radius (using a custom struct to only affect that corner):

```
Color("lapiz").ignoresSafeArea()
                        .customCornerRadius(CGSize(width: 125, height: 125), corners: .bottomRight)
```

Of course, there's more code than that, but that's what deals with making the corner radius. Here is the `.customCornerRadius` extension code and struct:

```
public extension View {
    
    func customCornerRadius(_ radius: CGSize, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( CustomRoundedCorner(size: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

```
struct CustomRoundedCorner: Shape {
    
    var size: CGSize
    var corners: UIRectCorner
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: size)
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

The `CGSize` width and height passed into the `.customCornerRadius` is currently set to 125. Say I attached this to a @State variable.

How would I animate the view to switch between, for example, a `CGSize` of 100? Could I have this repeat indefinitely, back and forth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Shape` inherits and `CGSize` conforms to the `Animatable` protocol, you can just add your `var animatableData` right to the `CustomRoundedCorner` shape.

```
struct CustomRoundedCorner: Shape {
    
    var size: CGSize
    var corners: UIRectCorner

    var animatableData: CGSize {
        get { return size }
        set { size = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: size)
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

After that, using your future `@State` variable, the CGSize should animate when the size changes.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm